# Firefox doesn't appear in the processes list, even though it's running normally. Is that normal?

Tags: 20.04, firefox, process

I'm using Ubuntu 20.04 LTS. Firefox is the only browser installed here, so it's the only one I use. However, the processes list, both in the System Monitor and in the Terminal, doesn't contain a "Firefox" process.

Is that normal or is it a sign that there is something wrong with the system?

Comment: Have you tried `ps ax | grep -i firefox` or similar? For me, it does show several processes as `/usr/lib/firefox/firefox`. in Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS.

Comment: @mivk I tried `ps | grep -i firefox`. Looking at the command you have mentioned, looks like I misused the command. Now it shows several processes as `/usr/lib/firefox/firefox`, like yours. Still, nothing appear at the system monitor. Do you think it's normal?

Comment: In System Monitor, it will show as "Web Content" and others under the "Process Name" column. You have to enable the "Command Line" column to see "firefox".

Comment: @mivk I have enabled the "Command Line" column and now I can see firefox's processes. All right now. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With help of [@mivk](https://askubuntu.com/users/8822/mivk) in the [comments](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1369655/firefox-doesnt-appear-in-the-processes-list-even-though-its-running-normally/1428089#comment2354295_1369655), I found that the command below shows the Firefox process in the terminal:

```
ps ax | grep -i firefox
```

The processes appear as `/usr/lib/firefox/firefox` in Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS.

In System Monitor, the Firefox process is shown as "Web Content" and others under the *Process Name* column. You have to enable the *Command Line* column to see "Firefox".